# Arbitrary length string & space regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out how to write a regex to find the following string:

"10R", "CRE"

It will need to look for a **double quote** followed by **some string (various lengths)**, followed by a **double quote**, followed by a **comma**, followed by **one or many spaces**, followed by a **double quote** followed by **some string (various lengths)**, followed by a **double quote**;

I have been a developer for years but RegEx makes me feel so dumb :(

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"\w*",\s+"[\w\s]*"`

That should match your requirements, [check out the regex here](http://regexr.com?328p7).

Note: If your language is placing the regex inside quotes, you may need to escape the double quotes (`"`)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with the string I want to match and there was one thing I forgot to mention. the second string of text ("CRE") can have white space as well ("10R", "CRE 2&11"). How could I modify this regex to work with that?

Comment: @user1695512 `"\w*",\s+"[\w\s]*"`.

Comment: @user1695512 I have updated it with xiaomao suggestions. If the answer helped you, you can accept it by hitting the green checkmark underneath the vote total.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
\"\w+\",\s+\"\w\"
```

Escaping may be optional depending on the context.

Also, not all regex engines know what `\w` and `\s` classes are, so you may need to define them in some other way.